# Select all rows from a table where a value is NOT found?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

**ve_survey_questions**

```
Qid | Question | CategoryId
```

**ve_survey_answers**

```
AnswerID | QuestionId | Answer
```

**ve_survey_useranswers**

```
id | UserId | QuestionId | AnswerId | Datetime
```

This is a multiple choice test. So `ve_s_Q` is all possible questions, `ve_s_A` is the possible multiple-choice answers, and `ve_s_useranswers` links the answer chosen by that particular user.

I'm trying to display every question that the user has NOT yet answered with a two step query:

```
    //check user answers
     $surveyanswerQ = "SELECT * FROM ve_survey_useranswers ORDER BY QuestionId";
     $surveyanswerResult = mysqli_query($db, $surveyanswerQ);
     $surveyanswer=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($surveyanswerResult);

     //select all unanswered questions
     $surveyQ = "SELECT * FROM ve_survey_questions q 
                          JOIN ve_survey_answers a 
                          ON q.Qid=a.QuestionId 
                          WHERE q.Qid <> {$surveyanswer['QuestionId']} 
                          ORDER BY a.QuestionId LIMIT 4 ";
     $surveyResult = mysqli_query($db, $surveyQ);
```

This does not work as supposed to... How can I write a better query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single sql:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM ve_survey_questions q
LEFT JOIN ve_survey_useranswers ua ON ua.QuestionId = q.Qid AND ua.UserId = xyz
WHERE ua.QuestionId IS NULL
```

Replace xyz with the UserId

To show all answers of unanswered questions (for example UserId = 1):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM ve_survey_answers a
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT q.*
  FROM ve_survey_questions q
  LEFT JOIN ve_survey_useranswers ua ON ua.QuestionId = q.Qid AND ua.UserId = 1
  WHERE ua.QuestionId IS NULL
) AS tb1 ON a.QuestionId = tb1.Qid
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58426/discussion-on-answer-by-fabrizio-caldarelli-how-to-select-all-rows-from-a-table).

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm understanding the schema right, this should work with a LEFT OUTER JOIN with a subquery:

```
SELECT q.*, ua.UserId, ua.Answer
FROM ve_survey_questions q 
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT u.*, a.QuestionId, a.Answer
     FROM ve_survey_useranswers u
     INNER JOIN ve_survey_answers a ON u.AnswerId = a.AnswerID
     WHERE u.UserId = @userid
     ) AS ua
ON q.Qid = ua.QuestionId 
WHERE ua.QuestionId IS NULL
ORDER BY q.Qid
```

So the subquery returns a row for each answered question for the given user (along with the answer they selected), then we use an outer join to see what questions are still unanswered.

You can eliminate the `WHERE ua.QuestionId IS NULL` if you instead want the full question list for that user, along with their answer, if there is one.

Comment: Brad I think the problem resides in the Left Outer JOIN. I try changing a.QuestionId to a.QuestionID and getting same duplicate name error.

Comment: Does the subquery part run properly by itself? You had some inconsistent casing in your examples (u.AnswerId vs a.AnswerID), not sure if that was a typo in your question, or if that reflects your actual schema. I'm not a mysql expert, but subqueries and outer joins should be pretty standard, the only thing I'm not positive about is the mysql syntax for subquery aliases. Do we need to do `) AS ua` instead?

Comment: (u.AnswerId vs a.AnswerID). No typo there it is as is. It's good. I'm not an expert either and so I cant answer your question.

Comment: Ok, [looks like mysql doesn't use the word OUTER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-simplification.html), try it now.